# UITableView header that covers more than one section

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with 4 sections. The first cell of each section acts as a header which, when selected, expands/collapses the rest of that section. Anyway, I would like to visually group these 4 sections into 2 groups of 2 so I want a way I can get a single header to cover 2 sections of the UITableView. At the moment I have headers above the 0th and 2nd sections and headers which are 0 pixels tall above sections 1 and 3 but when i scroll to section 1 the (invisible) section 1 header pushes the section 0 header out of view. Hoping someone can give me an idea of what to do.

Comment: I think it is easier to write that you need sections of sections in UITableView

Comment: did you set viewForHeader for zero height sections to nil?

Comment: Hmm, no I haven't. Can I do this without setting the viewForHeader for the headers I do want to be visible?

Comment: @NeverBe ok, i've tried this now. It didn't work.